# Ubuntu 18.04LTS hangs at purple loading screen in Virtualbox

Tags: boot, 18.04, virtualbox, windows-10

I'm trying to run Ubuntu 18.04LTS as a guest machine in Virtualbox on a Windows 10 host, but it just hangs at this screen:[image] And I have the settings for the VM as this:[image] I already have enabled virtualization in the bios and have disabled Hyper-v in Windows.

Comment: Hi, it's not clear how this relates to Ubuntu instead of VirtualBox or Windows, which is likely why you are being downvoted.  I suggest trying https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/virtualbox or https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/virtualbox.

Comment: Is there a reason why you're using 1.5x scaling for the video?